# How can I narrow the return type of a function property based on the boolean value of another property?

Tags: typescript

I want to have a type of the form `IA<T>` like

```
interface IA<T> {
  f: () => T | number;
  x: boolean
}
```

except that when `x` is `true` then `f` returns a `number`, and when `x` is `false` then `f` returns `T`. Is this possible? I tried

```
interface IA<T> {
 f: (this: IA<T>) => this['x'] extends true ? T : number;
 x: boolean
}
```

but it doesn't work:

```
const x0: IA<string> = { // error!
  f: () => "hello",
  x: true as const 
}
```

My goal is for the following code to work:

```
if (x0.x === true) {
   x0.f().toUpperCase(); // okay, it's a string
} else {
   x0.f().toFixed(); // okay, it's a number
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: • Please use conventional naming to prevent distractions; `a` is not a conventional interface name; could you try `A` maybe or anything in UpperCamelCase? • The problem you have seems to be absent from your code example, you've said "`x0` is not an instance of `A<T>`". Could you demonstrate that in the code itself so that it's a [mre] and we don't have to try to re-create the issue before attempting to solve it?

Comment: I've looked at this on and off for a few hours and it seems hopelessly muddled. Whatever you're trying is unlikely to work for a number of reasons. The main one: the type of `A<string>` is just `{f: (this: A<string>) => number; x: boolean}`. The `this` type doesn't magically defer for later use. As soon as you try to assign `x0` to `A<string>` (without a [mre] I just *guess* that's what you want) you'll have an error. There are other issues, but a full detailing would be ten pages long. Maybe you want to [edit] to ask "how can I do Y" instead of "why doesn't X work (for an implied Y)"?

Comment: Are you committed to "why is this not working" instead of "how can I do this"?  Because again, the former is like a huge tour of all the ways this fails to work, and the latter is "use a union instead as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wzq4rm)". I'd think you want to see that, right?  So you might consider [edit]ing the question as I suggested, where you ask primarily about your use case with a possible aside like "I tried this but it didn't work".  Also, I'm still not sure what the point of the recursive `this` param is; you're not using it, and it just complicates things.

Comment: @jcalz I don't know Typescript very well. Thanks for your help. Feel free to edit my question.

Comment: I've edited the question. Please let me know if I've misrepresented your use case somehow. I'll write up an answer with the union type [as shown in this playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQj6GN), if it works for you.  If not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Looks good. That's what I was after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's only affordance for checking one property and having it affect the apparent type of other properties is to make your type a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  So let's make `IA<T>` a discriminated union:

```
type IA<T> =
    { x: true, f: () => T; } |
    { x: false, f: () => number }
```

(Note that it has to be a [`type` alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) and not an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces), but that shouldn't matter in most circumstances.)

Here the `x` property is the *discriminant*, using the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `true` and `false` to distinguish which member of the union you have.  Then you can assign your `x0` value as desired:

```
const x0: IA<string> = {
    f: () => "hello",
    x: true
} // okay
```

And perform the kind of narrowing you expect:

```
function foo(y: IA<string>) {    
    if (y.x === true) {
        y.f().toUpperCase() // okay
    } else {
        y.f().toFixed() // okay
    }    
}    
foo(x0); // okay
```

(I wrapped that in a function because TS is clever enough to notice that `x0` is always just the `true` case, since it [narrows on assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments), so the `x0.f().toFixed()` fails because it knows that branch cannot be entered.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgQQDwBUB8MC8wa5gbxgA8AuGEAJwFcoAaGAMzIAoBKLDFAbhgF8YAPjjyFSjAIYAbAM51GLdpgwA7KgFsARlAp9gwAMYB7ZdJDEADGURJTFAJbKA5hkwFhuJjDYcYAIgAWUJKShr607sRklDTAvHoMVMr6IHbGjIaGzGBWyLYOzuz4engwdgxeYAB0RFiYrtFQhRElVQxslSCGAKoQ0BQAwuKybBH8QbJuJS2VbawdhgBidkRQACYjJXGx8RnMROasXEA)

Comment: Is it possible for foo to work if y is of type IA<T> instead of IA<string>?

Comment: Have you tried it? Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6qyYW) maybe? I'm not sure why you're asking me; did you try it and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. [It](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgQQDwBUB8MC8wa5gbxgA8AuGEAJwFcoAaGAMzIAoBKLDFAbhgF8YAPjjyFSjAIYAbAM51GLdpgwA7KgFsARlAp9gwAMYB7ZdJDEADGURJTFAJbKA5hkwFhuJjDYcYAIgAWUJKShr607sRklDTAvHoMVMr6IHbGjIaGqGjMYFbI6Oz4engwdgxeYAB0RFiYrtFQhRElVQxslSCGAKoQ0BQAwuKybBH8QbJuJS2VbawdhgBidkRQACYjJXGx8RnMROasXEA) gives a squiggly.

Comment: oh yes, toUpperCase would no longer exist. Sorry, won't waste your time anymore.